# Is there a simple way to execute cypress tests parallelly without using dashboard?

Tags: testing, automation, cypress, github-actions, parallel-testing

I'm working on a cypress test execution on Github actions and I need to know whether there is a way to execute the tests in parallel mode without using the cypress dashboard (Open source solution)

Tried the solution with 'Sorry Cypress' (https://docs.sorry-cypress.dev/) but I was not able to execute the tests in CI/CD (Github Actions).

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Easiest solution was to execute tests in a few parallel nodes
  using the containers in CI/CD. This can simply be achieved on GitHub
  Actions using 'matrix:' property in the GitHub workflow.
- In each node, we can execute separate test files and archive the results in
  each node separately. And at the end (after tests in all nodes are
  completed) we can generate a test report based on the results of each
  node (using archived files) and publish the report.

This was the high-level idea on how I managed to do the parallel execution without
using the cypress dashboard. I know the solution is not perfect but,
it's a good workaround and it managed to cut-down my test execution time by more than 60%

Comment: I am stuck with some concern. Currently I am triggering Jenkins pipeline and test cases are executing sequentially. We want to execute test in parallel mode with cypress dashboard. Could you please elaborate more on your solution or point to any such article? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you have the cypress dashboard, you can simply enable the parallel tests since you are already paying for the features. In that case it would be very easy and you can just refer the cypress documentation for this